# Table fetch multiple rows on using join

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch data from 3 tables **pm_conv**,**user**,**photo** but after joining the 3rd table *photo* i get multiples rows i tried allot to get data in LIMIT 1 but cant .

**Here is the query**

```
SELECT 
    pm_conv. *, user.username, user.id, photo.url 
FROM 
    pm_conv 
JOIN 
    user ON CASE 
        WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = user.id 
        WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.sender_id = user.id 
        END
JOIN 
    photo ON CASE 
        WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = photo.user_id 
        WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.sender_id = photo.user_id 
        END
WHERE 
    `sender_id`='2869' 
    OR `recipient_id` ='2869' 
ORDER BY  
    `last_answer_date` DESC
```

Comment: Do you getting any error ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Considering it's a conversation and your query means you want to get all the messages involving user 2869, you will really get multiple results. 

What I don't understand is, you said that even though you used limit 1, you're still getting multiple results? You probably misplaced your LIMIT 1.

Comment: Yes its a 3 table based on converstion .
I want to fetch conv,username and photo respectively from these tables 
But photo table gives multiple rows because it has more than one photo against one id

Comment: What is your condition on which photo the user is currently using? Do you have another relevant column in photo table that might address this question?

Comment: i m matching the id from pm_conv table to photo's user_id colum 
e.g id =3562 and in photo.user_id has 4 rows with the column user_id

Comment: @ArslanAli How will I determine which of the 4 photos will be used? The one with the latest "upload" date (if there are any), etc..?

Comment: Check this
https://www.mediafire.com/?0bhs6b7bxuzjiz4

Comment: @sugspnk the first one every time

Comment: What are the columns of your photo table?

Comment: `id`,`url`,`thumb_url`,`user_id`,`date`,`status`,`votes`,`comments`,`views`,`text`,`rotation`

Comment: i want only url on the basis of user_id

Comment: Thanks For your response .
Problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subquery instead , for photo table. May be it should work.

```
SELECT 
        pm_conv. *, 
        user.username, 
        user.id, 
        IF(pm_conv.sender_id ='2869', 
            (SELECT photo.user_id FROM photo WHERE pm_conv.recipient_id = photo.user_id LIMIT 1 ) , 
            IF (pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869', 
                (SELECT photo.user_id FROM photo WHERE pm_conv.recipient_id = photo.user_id LIMIT 1 ), 
                '')) as PHOTO_USER
    FROM 
        pm_conv 
    JOIN 
        user ON CASE 
            WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
                THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = user.id 
            WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
                THEN pm_conv.sender_id = user.id 
            END

    WHERE 
        `sender_id`='2869' 
        OR `recipient_id` ='2869' 
    ORDER BY  
        `last_answer_date` DESC
```

Comment: Thank You so much sir :)
You saved my day :)

Comment: Pleasure is all mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
SELECT 
    pm_conv. *, user.username, user.id, photo.url 
FROM 
    pm_conv 
JOIN 
    user ON CASE 
        WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = user.id 
        WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.sender_id = user.id 
        END
JOIN 
    photo ON CASE 
        WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = photo.user_id 
        WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.sender_id = photo.user_id 
        END
WHERE 
    `sender_id`='2869' 
    OR `recipient_id` ='2869' 
ORDER BY  
    `last_answer_date` DESC limit 1
```

**Modified query:-**

```
SELECT 
    pm_conv. *, user.username, user.id, photo.url 
FROM 
    pm_conv 
JOIN 
    user ON CASE 
        WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = user.id 
        WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.sender_id = user.id 
        END
JOIN ((SELECT `photo`.* FROM `photo` join `pm_conv` as pmc ON CASE 
        WHEN pmc.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pmc.recipient_id = photo.user_id 
        WHEN pmc.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pmc.sender_id = photo.user_id 
        END limit 1)) as photo
     ON CASE 
        WHEN pm_conv.sender_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.recipient_id = photo.user_id 
        WHEN pm_conv.recipient_id ='2869' 
            THEN pm_conv.sender_id = photo.user_id 
        END
WHERE 
    `sender_id`='2869' 
    OR `recipient_id` ='2869' 
ORDER BY  
    `last_answer_date` DESC
```

I thing it will give your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But it limits the whole data i just want to limit photo.url

Comment: Okay your  photo.url have  repeated value in table.

Comment: yes...because its has more urls of image against each id

Comment: @ArslanAli just try the modified query it will help you.